# How to specify a "Connection String" or "Advanced Settings" for use with the SQL Cache used by Code Contracts?

Tags: visual-studio, caching, visual-studio-2013, code-contracts, localdb

I would like to set the cache *database* used with Microsoft Code Contracts to use a LocalDB instance where the MDF is *not* located at the default data location. (For the sake of this question I am not interested in changing the LocalDB behavior through registry settings.)

Normally the database file can be specified in a Connection String and specifying the MDF path.

However, the [poorly documented](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) "SQL Server Field" in the Code Contracts project setting tab only seems to accept a SQL Server instance - eg. `(LocalDB)\v11` - and not a connection string making it a very large hammer.

When I try to specify a Connection String (eg. "Data Source=..") in the field, I get an error such as

> Cannot load assembly 'Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial'

which makes me believe this field does alot more than it indicates.

*How are such "advanced scenarios" specified/handled for a Code Contract cache?*

(My case involves the desire to choose the MDF path: but what about credentials? or a different database within the same instance?)

Comment: Bits of *outdated* "documentation" here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d174edff-ee75-4591-9d73-6cdc358fd16c/caching-and-cachesqlserver?forum=codecontracts